Marker image over relative image
Is it possible to place a marker image over a relative image,
without changing the position of the marker image?
If the size of the relative image changes, the position of the marker
image on the underlying image should remain the same.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">


  <style>
    .img {
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .marker {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" />
  <img class="marker" src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpinP4M2.png" style="width:50px" />

</body>

</html>




The position: relative won't affect the position of your marker as it's not a parent container of the marker. Consider wrapping both in a "wrapper", e.g. <div> and place the position: relative on the parent container

How is it more specific? OP is misusing/misunderstanding what the position: relative is actually doing

This question is more specific than either of the questions marked as duplicates, and so the answers to those questions don't really go all the way to answering your question. The OP is asking how to overlay a marker which maintains a fixed position as the underlying image is resized. I have voted to reopen this question. In the meantime, you can have a look at this example of a responsive image with overlaid markers maintaining their position. The key is to use percentage positions for the marker.

They key point OP missed is the correct use of position: relative and now the marker's position is absolute according to the body element, where wants it's to be relative to the image. Even the answer posted below is not explaining this

Not quite sure what the end goal is, if it's needed for the map, it doesn't do it that way at all, it does it through the API of the map service you're using.
And if you just need it on a picture, the simplest way is to first make a common container for pictures, and then resize the picture according to it and calculate marker coordinates in percent. In percent it will remain always in the necessary ratio, but whether this accuracy is enough for you I do not know. For the map picture it probably will not be very suitable, but for other purposes quite well


.img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 10%;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
     <img class="img" src="https://imgsrv2.voi.id/HpO09gZIQxpPSpVKdPkkZwaQELHpXUDAgoUw26q-tiA/auto/1200/675/sm/1/bG9jYWw6Ly8vcHVibGlzaGVycy8xNTE4MjMvMjAyMjAzMzEwODA3LW1haW4uSlBH.jpg"/>
      <img class="marker" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/302636/map-marker.svg" style="width:50px"/> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>




It's not for a map application, but something similar.
I want to mark several positions over a photo, very precisely. The displacement in the code example is too large for my use case. Is there a more precise way, or do I get around creating the photo and the markers absolute positions? Best regards
Jens
